# Can my output of Pandas dataframe be graphed?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

```
import dash, matplotlib
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd



data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Pandas\\$$$$.xlsx')
data2 = data.groupby(['Department']).count()
print data2
```

prints out exactly the information i need, however can i plot this?

C:\Users\dbeiler\Desktop\Pandas>python PythonApplication1.py

```
        Email  Completion

Department

dep1         165          62

dep2         147          68

dep3          37           8
```

ideally i'd like to use plotly if convenient https://plot.ly/products/dash/

Comment: Have a go at [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949174/3491991) - I think it could help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can build plot from your pandas dataframe. Folow instructions from guide : https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started

Simpliest way to build plot is:

```
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(
                id='mapbox',
                figure={
                    'data': [go.Bar(
                            x = data ['PutXcolumnNameHere'],
                            y = data ['PutYcolumnNameHere'],
                            )
                    ],
                    'layout': go.Layout(
                        legend={'x': 0, 'y': 1},
                        hovermode='closest'
                    )
                }
        )
    )
```