# Deploy a Python (Dash) app to Heroku using Conda environments (instead of virtualenv)

Tags: python, git, heroku

When I run `git push heroku master` to deploy my app to Heroku I keep getting errors

> Heroku Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

The problem was that the `requirements.txt` file I made with

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

made a dump of my system wide Python libraries instead of just the libraries in my `virtualenv` ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917628/heroku-push-fails-repeatedly-appears-to-fail-on-installing-bonjour/9917904#9917904)). This was very strange because I froze those requirements from my active virtualenv - this behavior should not have been possible.

`virtualenv` on windows has always slowed me down so I'm ready to try a new environment manager.

I want to use `conda` but am struggling to deploy with it to Heroku. I followed [Heroku's instructions for conda build-packs](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/conda/conda-buildpack) only to get vague/unhelpful errors at build time.

How can I deploy a Python app to Heroku using Conda environments?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Heroku doesn't care if you're using `virtualenv` or `conda` to manage environments. Using one or the other is mostly irrelevant to the deployment process.

Don't bother with the [Conda Environment Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/conda/conda-buildpack) instructions since those are for deploying a remote `conda` environment which is not what you are trying to do. You, my friend, are trying to deploy a remote *your_app* environment.

### Here's how to do that with a [dash application](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) and `conda`:

#### Create a new folder for your project:

```
$ mkdir dash_app_example
$ cd dash_app_example
```

#### Initialize the folder with git

```
$ git init # initializes an empty git repo
```

#### Create an `environment.yml` file in `dash_app_example`:

```
name: dash_app #Environment name
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pip:
    - dash
    - dash-renderer
    - dash-core-components
    - dash-html-components
    - plotly
    - gunicorn # for app deployment
```

#### Create the environment from `environment.yml`:

```
$ conda env create
```

#### Activate the conda environment

```
$ source activate dash_app #Writing source is not required on Windows
```

#### Confirm that the environment you're in is correct.

It should currently be in dash_app:

```
$ conda info --envs #Current environment is noted by a *
```

#### Initialze the folder with `app.py`, `requirements.txt`, and a `Procfile`:

---

`app.py`

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import os

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

app.css.append_css({"external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"})

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2('Hello World'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['LA', 'NYC', 'MTL']],
        value='LA'
    ),
    html.Div(id='display-value')
])

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('display-value', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def display_value(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

---

`Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn app:server
```

---

`requirements.txt`: describes your Python dependencies. You can fill this file in automatically by running `$ pip freeze > requirements.txt` on the command line.

---

#### Your folder structure should look like

```
- dash_app_example
--- app.py
--- environment.yml
--- Procfile
--- requirements.txt
```

Notice how there's no environment data in this directory. That's because `conda` unlike `virtualenv` stores all your environments in one place neatly away from your app directory. There's no need to `.gitignore` those files... they're not here!

#### Initialize Heroku, add files to Git, and deploy

```
$ heroku create my-dash-app # change my-dash-app to a unique name
$ git add . # add all files to git
$ git commit -m 'Initial app boilerplate'
$ git push heroku master # deploy code to heroku
$ heroku ps:scale web=1  # run the app with a 1 heroku "dyno"
```

Sources:

1. [Deploying an application with Heroku (using Conda Environments)](https://zduey.github.io/snippets/app-deployment-with-heroku/)
2. [My Python Environment Workflow with Conda](https://tdhopper.com/conda/)
3. [Deploying Dash Apps](https://plot.ly/dash/deployment) (using `virtualenv`)

Comment: Awesome summary, my friend

Comment: what if the package cannot be installed via pip, and must be installed via conda?

Comment: I do believe it will still work as PIP looks at installed python packages (I don't believe they had to be installed by pip).

Comment: @liang the answer is it won't work if the package cannot be installed via pip. Either use docker to set up non-pip dependencies, or use the `apt` Buildpack to install additional dependencies via `apt install` https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt