# Deploying Python App created in Conda environment to Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, anaconda, conda, heroku-cli

I have created a chatbot using Tensorflow in a conda environment and want to deploy it to Heroku

I first tried deploying the app to Heroku using Terminal and the Heroku CLI, but after detecting a Conda App, I got this message:

```
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/2abac4b7166986c6b1b33fcacccb13fb4e2036a9358f31ed8886bbf37c9987c7fbb8243090f0438ebbf02852a1cbeb1b5cae47f67dc2670115ce6d7bd2468300/bin/steps/conda_compile: line 9: conda: command not found
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python/Conda app.
```

Tried the same through the terminal box provided in PyCharm, but still got the same message.

I have already installed the Conda buildpack Heroku provides, which is perhaps why it recognizes the conda environment.

I tried doing this without the Conda buildpack but kept getting stuck when it came to installing the anaconda dependencies.

PS: Please do not refer me to this question: [Deploy a Python (Dash) app to Heroku using Conda environments (instead of virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949173/deploy-a-python-dash-app-to-heroku-using-conda-environments-instead-of-virtua)
It is not relevant to what I am trying to do.

Comment: What does "I have already installed the Conda buildpack Heroku provides" mean? Buildpacks aren't something you install.

Comment: @Chris I meant I created the heroku git repository by running this: ```heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/conda/conda-buildpack.git```

Comment: That buildpack hasn't been updated in over four years. There appear to be several other conda / anaconda buildpacks. I suggest you try a few different ones.