# how to deploy flask with anaconda application to heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, anaconda, conda

I have developed a python flask application which is using the conda environment. This app is not working without the conda environment (because pycrypto module used in this app requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 ...), Anyways, how to deploy this app with this established environment to heroku???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy a Python (Dash) app to Heroku using Conda environments (instead of virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949173/deploy-a-python-dash-app-to-heroku-using-conda-environments-instead-of-virtua)

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?