# git push heroku master - error in requirements.txt file

Tags: python, git, heroku, anaconda

I was pushing my app through Heroku master but this was the error I received. I tried resolving the problem by deleting some of the files that were showing up as errors.

Earlier, I was getting an error in pushing the Heroku master too:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/absl-py_1607439979954/work'

terminal:

```
Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting absl-py
remote:          Downloading absl_py-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.12
remote:          Downloading alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-project==0.9.1 (from -r /tmp/build_da51543d/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for anaconda-project==0.9.1 (from -r /tmp/build_da51543d/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to skin-lesion-detector.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/skin-lesion-detector.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/skin-lesion-detector.git'
```

This is my file for requirements.txt

```
absl-py==0.11.0
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.10.0
anaconda-project==0.9.1
applaunchservices==0.2.1
appnope==0.1.2
appscript==1.1.1
argh==0.26.2
argon2-cffi==20.1.0
asgiref==3.3.1
asn1crypto==1.4.0
astor==0.8.1
astroid==2.4.2
astropy==4.2
astunparse==1.6.3
async-generator==1.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==20.3.0
autopep8==1.5.4
Babel==2.9.0
backcall==0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bitarray==1.6.1
bkcharts==0.2
bleach==3.2.1
bokeh==2.2.3
boto==2.49.0
Bottleneck==1.3.2
brotlipy==0.7.0
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
cloudpickle==1.6.0
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.4.4
conda==4.9.2
conda-build==3.21.4
conda-package-handling==1.7.2
conda-verify==3.4.2
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
cryptography==3.3.1
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.21
cytoolz==0.11.0
dask==2020.12.0
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20200713
distributed==2020.12.0
Django==3.1.5
docutils==0.16
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.1.0
filelock==3.0.12
flake8==3.8.4
Flask==1.1.2
flatbuffers==1.12
fsspec==0.8.3
future==0.18.2
gast==0.4.0
gevent==20.12.1
glob2==0.7
gmpy2==2.0.8
google-auth==1.22.1
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
graphviz==0.16
greenlet==0.4.17
grpcio==1.32.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h5py==2.10.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
heroku==0.1.4
html5lib==1.1
idna==2.10
imagecodecs==2020.5.30
imageio==2.9.0
imagesize==1.2.0
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
intervaltree==3.1.0
ipykernel==5.3.4
ipython==7.19.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.6.3
isort==5.6.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jedi==0.14.1
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==1.0.0
json5==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.7
jupyter-console==6.2.0
jupyter-core==4.7.0
jupyterlab==2.2.6
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-server==1.2.0
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
Keras==2.4.3
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keyring==21.8.0
kiwisolver==1.3.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libarchive-c==2.9
llvmlite==0.34.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==4.6.2
Markdown==3.3.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.2.0
mkl-random==1.1.1
mkl-service==2.3.0
mock==4.0.3
more-itertools==8.6.0
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack==1.0.1
multipledispatch==0.6.0
navigator-updater==0.2.1
nbclient==0.5.1
nbconvert==6.0.7
nbformat==5.1.2
nbzip==0.1.0
nest-asyncio==1.4.3
networkx==2.5
nltk==3.5
nose==1.3.7
notebook==6.1.6
numba==0.51.2
numexpr==2.7.2
numpy==1.19.5
numpydoc==1.1.0
oauthlib==3.1.0
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
openpyxl==3.0.6
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==20.8
pandas==1.2.0
pandocfilters==1.4.3
parso==0.5.2
partd==1.1.0
path==15.0.1
pathlib2==2.3.5
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.5.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.1.0
pip==20.3.3
pkginfo==1.6.1
pluggy==0.13.1
ply==3.11
prometheus-client==0.9.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.8
protobuf==3.13.0
psutil==5.7.2
ptyprocess==0.7.0
py==1.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser==2.20
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.6
pydocstyle==5.1.1
pydot==1.4.1
pydot-ng==2.0.0
pydotplus==2.0.2
pyerfa==1.7.1.1
pyflakes==2.2.0
Pygments==2.7.4
pylint==2.6.0
pyodbc==4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.17.3
PySocks==1.7.1
pytest==0.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server==0.4.0
python-language-server==0.31.7
pytz==2020.5
PyWavelets==1.1.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==20.0.0
QDarkStyle==2.8.1
QtAwesome==1.0.1
qtconsole==4.7.7
QtPy==1.9.0
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rope==0.18.0
rsa==4.6
Rtree==0.9.4
ruamel-yaml==0.15.87
scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.5.2
seaborn==0.11.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
setuptools==51.1.2.post20210112
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.15.0
sklearn==0.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sortedcollections==1.2.3
sortedcontainers==2.3.0
soupsieve==2.1
Sphinx==3.4.3
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.2.4
spyder==4.0.1
spyder-kernels==1.8.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.21
sqlparse==0.4.1
statsmodels==0.12.1
sympy==1.7.1
tables==3.6.1
tblib==1.7.0
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.9.2
testpath==0.4.4
Theano==1.0.5
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tifffile==2021.1.14
toml==0.10.1
toolz==0.11.1
tornado==6.1
tqdm==4.55.1
traitlets==5.0.5
typed-ast==1.4.2
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
ujson==4.0.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3==1.26.2
watchdog==0.10.4
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wheel==0.36.2
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.12.1
wurlitzer==2.0.1
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==1.3.7
xlwings==0.21.4
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
yapf==0.30.0
zict==2.0.0
zipp==3.4.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

Comment: "*ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/absl-py_1607439979954/work'*" No, this time the error is different.

Comment: yes, I fixed the previous error but bumped into a new one lol pls help

Comment: There is no `anaconda-project` at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-project/. You cannot install it with `pip` from `requirements.txt`. Perhaps it should be installed using `conda`.

Comment: what amendments should I make to the code or the requirements file? cause after pushing heroku master, it automatically uses pip to install requirements

Comment: You cannot install `anaconda-project` from `requirements.txt`. There have to be a different way or a different set of dependencies. This, may be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949174/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anaconda+heroku