# Using conda and flask to host on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, conda

Hi I have a flask app using conda as my env that I am trying to host on heroku. I do not have any buildpacks setup as I have been following [Deploy a Python (Dash) app to Heroku using Conda environments (instead of virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949173/deploy-a-python-dash-app-to-heroku-using-conda-environments-instead-of-virtua) as a guide. The issue is that my requirements.txt has an issue saying
Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Ignored the following yanked versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda==23.10.0 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda==23.10.0
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

sorry if this is a dumb question I am kind of new to this.

```
archspec==0.2.1
boltons==23.0.0
Brotli==1.0.9
certifi==2023.7.22
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
conda==23.10.0
conda-content-trust==0.2.0
conda-libmamba-solver==23.11.1
conda-package-handling==2.2.0
conda_package_streaming==0.9.0
cryptography==41.0.3
idna==3.4
jsonpatch==1.32
jsonpointer==2.1
libmambapy==1.5.3
packaging==23.1
pip==23.3
pluggy==1.0.0
pycosat==0.6.6
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==23.2.0
PySocks==1.7.1
requests==2.31.0
ruamel.yaml==0.17.21
setuptools==68.0.0
tqdm==4.65.0
truststore==0.8.0
urllib3==1.26.18
wheel==0.41.2
zstandard==0.19.0
```

enviorment.yml

```
name: name
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_gnu
  - aiohttp=3.9.0=py312h5eee18b_0
  - aiosignal=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=23.2.0=pyh71513ae_0
  - bidict=0.21.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py312ha883a20_0
  - brotli-python=1.0.9=py312h6a678d5_7
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - ca-certificates=2023.12.12=h06a4308_0
  - cachetools=5.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - certifi=2023.11.17=py312h06a4308_0
  - cffi=1.16.0=py312h5eee18b_0
  - charset-normalizer=3.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.1.7=unix_pyh707e725_0
  - cryptography=41.0.7=py312hdda0065_0
  - expat=2.5.0=h6a678d5_0
  - flask=2.2.2=py312h06a4308_0
  - flask-cors=3.0.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - flask-socketio=5.3.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - frozenlist=1.4.0=py312h5eee18b_0
  - google-auth=2.26.0=pyhca7485f_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gspread=5.7.1=pyh1a96a4e_0
  - gunicorn=21.2.0=py312h7900ff3_1
  - httplib2=0.22.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - idna=3.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - intel-openmp=2023.1.0=hdb19cb5_46306
  - itsdangerous=2.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py312h06a4308_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.38=h1181459_1
  - libexpat=2.5.0=hcb278e6_1
  - libffi=3.4.4=h6a678d5_0
  - libgcc-ng=13.2.0=h807b86a_3
  - libgomp=13.2.0=h807b86a_3
  - libnsl=2.0.1=hd590300_0
  - libsqlite=3.44.2=h2797004_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libuuid=2.38.1=h0b41bf4_0
  - libxcrypt=4.4.36=hd590300_1
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py312h5eee18b_0
  - mkl=2023.1.0=h213fc3f_46344
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py312h5eee18b_1
  - mkl_fft=1.3.8=py312h5eee18b_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.4=py312hdb19cb5_0
  - multidict=6.0.4=py312h5eee18b_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h6a678d5_0
  - numexpr=2.8.7=py312hf827012_0
  - numpy=1.26.3=py312hc5e2394_0
  - numpy-base=1.26.3=py312h0da6c21_0
  - oauth2client=4.1.3=py_0
  - oauthlib=3.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=3.2.0=hd590300_1
  - packaging=23.1=py312h06a4308_0
  - pandas=2.1.4=py312h526ad5a_0
  - pip=23.3.1=py312h06a4308_0
  - pyasn1=0.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyjwt=2.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=23.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=py312h06a4308_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyha2e5f31_6
  - python=3.12.1=hab00c5b_1_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-dotenv=1.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - python-engineio=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-socketio=5.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python_abi=3.12=4_cp312
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=py312h06a4308_0
  - pyu2f=0.1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - readline=8.2=h5eee18b_0
  - requests=2.31.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rsa=4.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - setuptools=68.2.2=py312h06a4308_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h5eee18b_0
  - tbb=2021.8.0=hdb19cb5_0
  - tk=8.6.13=noxft_h4845f30_101
  - tzdata=2023c=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - websockets=12.0=py312h98912ed_0
  - werkzeug=2.2.3=py312h06a4308_0
  - wheel=0.41.2=py312h06a4308_0
  - xz=5.4.5=h5eee18b_0
  - yarl=1.9.3=py312h5eee18b_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - pip:
      - h11==0.14.0
      - simple-websocket==1.0.0
      - wsproto==1.2.0
prefix: path
```

As a test I removed these lines from my file and then it complied but threw this error
Activity Feed Build Log
ID fd58a07e-c62a-4935-8e60-92757520bcb8

-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
!     No default language could be detected for this app.
HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
!     Push failed.